# Unexpected return type when using `useQuery` from @trpc/react-query

Tags: typescript, debugging, prisma, trpc.io

Full source [here](https://github.com/gregoryterlecki/typescript-app-demo/tree/add-tRPC-and-Prisma), for reference.

I'm fairly new to TypeScript, and brand new to NextJS (13.4) and tRPC. I'm working on building something to understand how the stack works.

For a quick bit of context, `@trpc/react-query` extends your server routes definition by giving you access to, among many other functions, `useQuery`. One of the options you can provide to `useQuery` as an argument is `initialData`, which allows you to pre-populate the results of the query.

[image: The code where I invoke useQuery]
which is in `src/app/_components/UserListClient.tsx`

[image: What I see in VS Code when I hover over initialData, underlined in red in the image above]
What I see in VS Code when I hover over initialData, underlined in red in the image above

[image: What I see when hovering over initialUsers, which is being supplied as the value for initialData from the first screenshot]

This is I see when hovering over initialUsers, which is being supplied as the value for initialData from the first screenshot

Looking into the error, I see that `useQuery` expects the data provided to be an array of users, except instead of expecting the users to have `updatedAt` and `createdAt` as dates, it expects strings.

However, my server router definition for the `user.list` procedure clearly defines the return type to have dates with a `Date` type, not a string, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: from my router definition]

What is the problem? Why does `useQuery` know about the correct return type, with the odd specific exception where it appears to turn `Date` types into string types?

I tried inspecting the types that `useQuery` expects, but as I said, since I'm fairly new to TypeScript I found it quite difficult to trace back the types to see if at any point `useQuery` is casting my types, or anything like that. Not sure how to approach this, and not sure how to debug.

Answer (score 0):

tRPC is using JSON to serialize data. As JSON does not have a `Date` type, JSON.stringify would convert a `Date` to a string:

```js
JSON.stringify({createdAt: new Date()})
// {"createdAt":"2023-11-14T15:50:32.170Z"}
```

If you really want to use `Date` types instead of the string representation, have look at transformers using superjson:

https://trpc.io/docs/server/data-transformers#using-superjson